# Lotus Notes: Getting all notes in a view or folder, sorted by column, through C-API

Tags: lotus-notes

I am trying to write an application which accesses Notes databases through the C API, this works so far as I can get the list (summary info) of the notes in a view or folder with `NIFOpenCollection()` and `NIFReadEntries()`.

However, this will return the notes in a seemingly arbitrary order. How can I retrieve all notes in a view or folder, sorted by a specific column? `NIFSetCollation()` doesn't seem to help with that, as it only allows to specify a collation/order which is already defined in the template(?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collation has to have been previously defined in the design of the NSF file that you are accessing.  I.e., NIFSetCollation should work, but you have to have laid the groundwork for it first.  Normally, one would do this by using Domino Designer to set up the column sorting for the views that your code is accessing. It would be far more ambitious to try to actually write code to set up the collation in the view from scratch.

(BTW: A template is a separate file, usually an NTF, from which an NSF can inherit design elements, including column sorting for views. But this is not a runtime relationship as far as your code will be concerned. Templates are not relevant here.)